# Return 0 if no results in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to query 2 different values in the same field, but if one of them has no results, I need the query to return 0

```
SELECT Test_Code, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM Test_Table with (nolock)
WHERE Start_Date >= dateadd(mi,-10,getdate()) AND
      (Test_Code='110' OR Test_Code='112')
GROUP BY Test_Code
```

Test_Code 110 will always have results, so no need to return 0 there.  But if Test_Code 112 has no results, I need the query to return 0.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @Slanderman . . . I added the SQL Server tag based on the syntax.

Comment: Great looks like you have a valid response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a list of all the values you want returned -- in case they don't exist in the table.  Then use a `left join`:

```
SELECT v.Test_Code, COUNT(tt.Test_code) as Count
FROM (VALUES ('110'), ('112')) v(test_code) LEFT JOIN
     Test_Table tt
     ON tt.Test_Code = v.Test_Code AND
        tt.Start_Date >= dateadd(minute, -10, getdate()) 
GROUP BY v.Test_Code
```